# Installing Playonlinux games onto a usb

Tags: usb, wine, games, playonlinux, chromebook

I downloaded ubuntu on my chromebook using crouton so i can play games but sadly I only have 16gb I have a 32gb usb and thats where I install all my games so I want to know how to install games onto my usb because whenever I download a game it takes up 1gb of my storage I want a way to store and play them from my usb i don't know if im using this properly so don't be rude I just need help if there's no way I to do so i will have to try something else thank you

Comment: Why not do a Full install of Ubuntu to USB and download and install games to that? https://askubuntu.com/questions/1217832/how-to-create-a-full-install-of-ubuntu-20-04-to-usb-device-step-by-step. A mkusb persistent USB might also work and save a bit of space and time.

Comment: im no expert and i dont know how to install ubuntu onto a usb but its a good idea however my sister will use it for school projects while ill use it for games my sister lost her usb somewhere in school

Comment: A good up to date guide for making a Persistent USB stick can be found here: https://www.linuxuprising.com/2019/03/create-persistent-storage-live-usb-with.html. You should be able to download games directly to the USB and play them from there. there is a NTFS partition that your sister can use for data, it is Windows compatible. Nice to share with your sister. It should not be long before you are ready to make a Full install USB.